# Clojure testing : testing the negation of an assertion

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

This works for me :

```
(is  (thrown? AbstractMethodError (.fun obj 1) ))
```

But this blows up

```
(is (not (thrown? AbstractMethodError (.fun obj 1) )))
```

with the following error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: thrown? in this context
```

Presumably "thrown?" has some special meaning inside the "is" and isn't visible when I put the "not" in the way.

So how can I test a negation of an assertion like thrown?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clojure unit-testing. How do I test if a function throws an exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32063244/clojure-unit-testing-how-do-i-test-if-a-function-throws-an-exception)

Comment: @NathanDavis It's related but this is meant to be a distinct part of a larger question.

Answer (score 5):

You're correct, `thrown?` is a [special assertion](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html) that must appear after `is`. If you want to test that an exception is not thrown (in other words, the call evaluated to something), you might want to do something like:

`(is (.fun obj 1))`

although that has one problem: it would fail if the result is falsey (false, nil). To be completely sure:

```
(let [r (.fun obj 1)]
  (is (= r r)))
```

(this is a tautology, and will only fail if it does throw an exception).

Comment: Actually, what I'm really interested in testing is whether obj actually HAS a method .fun. Can you think of a better way to do this?

Comment: Via the reflection api. See this answer, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821286/how-can-i-get-the-methods-of-a-java-class-from-clojure